# Laravel facebook login using socialite

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

Please check the website here [egypt-pets.com/login](http://egypt-pets.com/login) click on the facebook login and check the error page.

> My routes

```
Route::get('login/facebook', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/facebook/callback{token}', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

> My services.php

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => '**********',
        'client_secret' => '**********',
        'redirect' => 'http://egypt-pets.com/auth/facebook/callback',
    ],
```

> What I have tried

I have tried to check the facebook app but everything is right.
Also I check the client_sercret and client_id but both are correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook returns to this url of yours

> /auth/facebook/callback

And your routes file says

> /login/facebook/callback

This portion in your routes file is incorrect

> Route::get('login/facebook/callback{token}', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');

You can try this:

```
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

And then to get the callback token you can use the following code in your controller.

```
$code = \Request::input('code');
```

Hope this helps;

Comment: thank you for trying but I have changed the route as you said and nothing happened too.. the same error

Comment: i just realised that facebook returns to the following URL /auth/facebook/callback and you have login/facebook/callback -- one is /auth/ and the one is routes file is /login/

Comment: I tried as you said and now i got this error `Client error: `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?access_token=&fields=name,email,gender,verified,link&appsecret_proof=f2a00e56af56e4159a4cb6ed68ccd1ca2183c62498dbd8d712337f92bb3c0851` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthExce (truncated...)` :D

Comment: Remeber that the token is coming back as a GET variable. callback?code=. Remember to adjust and call the right token by using \Request::input('code') to be able to access the token correctly

Comment: Glad i could help